Como mostrar un Sweet Alert al seleccionar una fila de un ASPxGridView
Que tal gusto Saludarlos, tengo un detalle, estoy intentando que al seleccionar la fila de un ASPxGridView me muestre un mensaje de alerta previamente ya establecido pero no eh podido, tambien intento forzar a un postback de igual forma fallo. Espero puedan ayudarme
este es el mensaje:

y  asi tengo declarada el GridView


Envías toda la información al servidor, solo para que éste te devuelva un script que levanta una alerta..... no sería mejor levantar la alerta sin hacer postback???

El proceso lo estoy metiendo una condición mas o menos asi, Seleccionas la fila y al seleccionar recupera información referida a esa  misma la cual si el registro que viene dentro de la fila fue autorizado te manda a otro formulario en caso contrario mostraría ese mensaje que añadi en la pregunta, no se si me dia entender un poco de lo que tendría que hacer. Pero de igual forma si es mas fácil de la forma que sugieres, podrias decirme como realizarlo.

Ok, ahora entiendo mejor. Me queda la duda cuando hablas que tienes problema con el postback, estas diciendo que la función SelectionChanged no se ejecuta nunca???. Por otro lado, creo recordad (que esta tecnología es más vieja que mi abuela) que no es necesario enviar la etiqueta <script>, ya que se agrega automaticamente (igual no estoy 100% seguro de ello)

Lo otro, muy importante: todo código debe ir como texto (no como imágenes)

Si a la hora de aplicar el break point el SelectionChanged se ejecuta sin problema con lo demas, lo unico es que al parecer para que se arroje ese mensaje tendría que hacer un postback, algo que ya intente pero no me resulta, cual manera es la que tienes en mente.?
